# Deployment issue in Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, glassfish, web-deployment

I'm facing some deployment issue while trying to deploy main war file which initiates the task.

Totally there are 3 war files among that I'm able to deploy 2 war file successfully, but deployment fails for one specific war.

I'm facing this issue only couple of days back before that everything works fine.

No Changes were made in server settings .

I thought it could be an compilation issue so i tried to redeploy the backup file which was took in Aug,July but it throws me same exception.

```
error- Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect -- Connection refused: connect. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Server logs:

```
[#|2017-09-11T00:46:35.536-0700|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=65;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Redirecting to /index.jsf|#]

[#|2017-09-11T00:46:35.974-0700|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=67;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...|#]

[#|2017-09-11T00:47:13.642-0700|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=4387;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2017-09-11T00:47:16.756-0700|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=4374;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer prepare method|#]

[#|2017-09-11T00:47:16.756-0700|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=4374;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app|#]

[#|2017-09-11T00:47:16.756-0700|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=4374;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused -- Connection refused
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused -- Connection refused
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:193)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused -- Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.downloadFile(WebServicesDeployer.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.downloadWsdlsAndSchemas(WebServicesDeployer.java:300)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.setupJaxWSServiceForDeployment(WebServicesDeployer.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServicesDeployer.prepare(WebServicesDeployer.java:174)
    ... 53 more
|#]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot to go on here, but it looks like you have a JAX-WS web service which is trying to download a WSDL/Schema. The URL for that file may be wrong or unresolvable for some other reason because GlassFish cannot get the file it needs for deployment.